# How do I get pytesseract to find an integer value from this screenshot?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am running tesseract v5.3.3.20231005

[image]

I am trying to turn the number in this image above into an integer value.

Here is my code:

```
# Convert the extracted text to a number (if it contains numerical characters)
number_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(buy_offers_screenshot)

buy_offer = float(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, number_text)))
print(buy_offer)
```

But the response I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\tesseract.py", line 8, in <module>
    buy_offer = float(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, number_text)))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to get an integer value from this screenshot?

Comment: Please also include the full error message and stack trace for the ValueError (which you currently catch and then discard, hiding it with your own message)

Comment: Does that image work with an online tesseract ocr?

Comment: Why do you populate `buy_offer` then ignore it and populate `number_text`? What value is in `buy_offers_screenshot`? Please make sure your code is a ***complete*** [mre]

Comment: Good point - I just updated the code in the origonal response. Does this make more sense? I also included the terminal response. @MatBailie

Comment: The number_text must be empty could you double check.

Comment: when I remove the 'number text =' line, the response I get is: NameError: name 'number_text' is not defined @darthbaba

Comment: add print(number_text) line before buy_offer and report your output.

Comment: @darthbaba it comes back as an empty line - like nothing is there

Comment: @darthbaba how would I get this to detect the image text successfully? Thanks

Comment: The issue is with the image file itself, and the code looks correct, I ran the OCR with the image you shared and received nothing. So try changing the image file and running the code, It should work.

Comment: @darthbaba I changed the screenshot slightly and it worked! Not sure why that image was having trouble detecting. Thank you!